# Awk command to eliminate rows with specific empty fields

Tags: unix, awk

My task is to eliminate rows if 99th (last) column of these rows is empty. I tried below command:

```
awk '$99 !~ /\s+/' BRCA-TP.maf.annotated > test
```

It eliminated some of the rows with whitespace but I recognized some rows still have space in the place of 99th column.

The data I am working on is this:
http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/analyses__2014_10_17/reports/cancer/BRCA-TP/Mutation_Assessor/BRCA-TP.maf.annotated

Representation of above data:

```
---- col95   col96   col97   col98   col99   
row1 aaaa    aaaa    aaaa    aaaa  
row2 bbbb    bbbb    bbbb    bbbb  
row3 cccc    cccc    cccc    cccc
```

I wanted to eliminate all the rows with empty 94th column. But how? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This probably belongs on http://superuser.com

Comment: Don't make us go of looking at other sites and don't make us look at data with 94+ fields or many of us just won't bother. Just post a small sample input set of say 5 lines with 5 fields each that REPRESENTS your problem and the associated expected output.

Comment: Using tab as the delimiter, *none* of the rows in your 59MB (!) of sample data have a blank field 94.  Show  us, as per EdMorton's suggestion, some sample data that is truly useful for your problem.

Comment: I am sorry but I think the problem might be input specific. For this reason, I posted the data. The command is working for such small sample data but it is not working on the data for some reason. Possibly, it is caused by my lack of knowledge. Excuse me.

Comment: @DorukhanArslan Let me try again:  Precisely which of the lines in your 59MB of sample data did you think the code should remove?

Comment: zzevannn's answer is clear enough. Thank you.

@shellter It was a problem about tab delimitation. After changed awk command as zzevannn said, I saw last column is 99th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like the following would work for checking what you described.

```
awk -F'\t' '$94==""||$94==" "||$93=="neutral" {next;} {print;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

However, when I wget the file you provided as an example, it is tab delimited and has 99 columns, not 94.  Also, the file has `CRLF` line endings, so to awk its looking like the value of the last column is a carriage return. Using that sample with the below modification to the above awk seems to do what you want.

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN {RS="\r\n"} $99==""||$99==" "||$98=="neutral" {next;} {print;}' inputfile > outputfile
```

You'll want to do some reading on awk before diving right into usage. Your example script in the question is missing the `-F'\t'` argument to tell awk the file is tab delimited, you either need to remove the `CR` characters or tell awk the RS is `CRLF`, and you can chain together logical tests in front of a conditional block to more than one check.

Also, do heed the commenters advice on forming a better question, I had to go figure out a lot of things about your file on my own here, and most SO users won't do that for you.

Comment: You are right. I need more knowledge before experience maybe but I have no time, need to hurry. Please check last few rows after you run these commands. They should be eliminated but they are there still.

Comment: You may have tried this before I added the bit about carriage returns, it seems to be working for me.

Comment: I figured out at last my absurd mistake. I was insistently writing the command without "RS="\r\n". Since I did not add -F'\t' as well, I counted column number as 94 instead of 96. All of them are clear now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Not a problem.  Welcome to the world of awk gotchas.